# How to render MermaidJS into React Markdown Editor?

Tags: reactjs, mermaid

I'd like to render MermaidJS into the ReactMarkdown Viewer (https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown). I added a sample project here https://github.com/SamTV12345/stackedit-react/tree/feature/settingsmenu

To get started:

1. npm install
2. npm start
3. localhost:5173/app
4. Edit the MarkdownViewer found in src/components/MarkdownViewer.tsx

For those not wanting to checkout the repository. Here is the respective code:

```js
        <ReactMarkdown className="grid-none border-gray-100 border-2 rounded-2xl pl-4 pt-2 pb-2 pr-4 overflow-auto"
                       children={text}
                       components={{
                            code({node, inline, className, children, ...props}) {
                               const match = /language-(\w+)/.exec(className || '')
                               return !inline && match ? (
                                   <SyntaxHighlighter
                                       children={String(children).replace(/\n$/, '')}
                                       language={match[1]}
                                       PreTag="div"
                                       {...props}
                                   />
                               ) : (
                                   <code className={className} {...props}>
                                       {children}
                                   </code>
                               )
                           }
                       }}
                           remarkPlugins={[remarkMath, remarkGfm]}
            rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex,rehypeRaw]}
        />)
```

What I tried:

1. Use mermaid.render() but it renders it directly into the DOM and  throws an exception when rendered with non complete code.
2. Different mermaid plugins that are unfortunately deprecated and don't work with the latest node version. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mermaid2 -><2000 dependencies) and https://github.com/siddharthreddi/react-mermaid-pro not working above Node16